# Related links not obvious as links

Tags: bug, hyperlinks

In *pm.stackexchange.com*, Looking at the related links below they look like normal text and not distinct as links. They are not underlined  when mouse hover. Am using Google chrome browser, I don't think it is my browser.

[image]

Comment: Is this problem still outstanding?

Answer (score 1):

Just asked some other mods. It seems to be a known behaviour for *all* beta sites. Will check if there's further info on it, and if it's categorized as a bug or not.

**Edit:** As I haven't had an answer from other mods if that's an expected behaviour or not, I raised this question @ meta.stackoverflow: [Related Questions/Linked Questions on Stack Exchange beta sites not appearing as links when hovered](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/157441/157692)

Comment: yes, if you go to the main site, then click a question, then mouseover the links in the sidebar, they don't show underlined, not like they do on meta. It's not a problem specific to us, it's a bug on all beta sites. It's been tagged with "design" so that Jin, the SE designer, will fix this when he gets time.

Answer (score 0):

Mouse over them. They should be underlined and your cursor should become a hand.

Comment: They are not underlined. I've updated my answer. it's in _pm.StackExchange.com_

Comment: Indeed, I can confirm the same behavior here... in both Chrome + IE.